# Draggable, on Google AppMaker

Tags: marker, google-app-maker

I want a little guidance, because I haven't found the explanation I need yet.

I'm developing a website on Google App Maker, and I want to use on Google Map Widget a Draggable Marker.

All the info I have found, is like for an external website including HTML and JavaScript libraries. The error is shown when I type:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlon,
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
  title:"Drag me!"
});
```

> "Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.Marker is not a constructor
>   at var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({ (NewScript1: 143) ".

I have tried in client side script, and in server side script.

Question, if I want to use a marker I need to add libraries to appmaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are getting the error because you are executing your client script before Maps API is loaded. To be 100% sure that it is loaded you need to execute your code in `onAttach` event of the Google Map Widget (maybe `onDataLoad` one will work as well).

If you want to make the `Marker` that App Maker adds to the map by default draggable you can use this snippet:

```javascript
// Google Map widget's onAttach event handler
var marker = widget.getAddressMarkerJs();
marker.setDraggable(true);
```

In case you want to add all-new marker(s) you can use this snippet:

```javascript
// Google Map widget's onAttach event handler
var map = widget.getMapJs();

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
  title:"Drag me!"
});
```

**Bonus** snippet to remove default marker from the map

```javascript
// Google Map widget's onAttach event handler
var marker = widget.getAddressMarkerJs();
marker.setMap(null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pavel Shleinik, this worked: 

//Google Map widget's onAttach event handler
var marker = widget.getAddressMarkerJs();
marker.setDraggable(true);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google Maps, you need to consider it as a widget in the App Maker API which is slightly different from the Google Maps API you are using.

If you look at the App Maker API you will see how you can add markers to a maps widget and how to return them: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#GoogleMap

Comment: First of all Johan W. thanks so much for your kind response.

I know, i can use a marker, and, i can get latittude, longitude, change address. the thing i need, is the "marker to be draggable", so generate different latitude and longitude, thats why i need to be marker draggable.

Thats the issue i am having with the widget, i cant find that info.

Comment: The marker is not draggable in App Maker API as the GoogleMap widget only provides a fraction of the Google Maps API (showMarkers, showAdress, etc.). If you want to make the marker draggable, you need to add a key to the apiKey field in the **Property Editor**. The easiest way is to click on the field's question mark and go from there to the Google Maps API website. There you can get a standard key which you can use in your app to access the Maps object through the getMapJs() method.

Comment: You should be able to use the script you introduced, if you adapt it to the getMapJs() method:
`var maps = widget.getMapJs();
var marker = new maps.Marker({
  position: latlon,
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
  title:"Drag me!"
});`