# Google Appmaker MAP api draggable marker and save new coordinates

Tags: google-app-maker

I am currently working on a project using Google App maker and I have came across the google map API [Draggable Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544447/) question posted here.

I was wondering how to save the coordinates of the marker when I drag it along the map.

I have tried the code below but it saves the coordinates of the center of the map not the marker. [i've put a sample picture of what im planning to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAM0J.png)

```javascript
var marker = widget.getAddressMarkerJs();
marker.setDraggable(true);

record.latitude = widget.latitude();
record.longtitude = widget.longitude();
```

UPDATE**
This is my code now (an abomination >__<)

```
var marker = widget.getAddressMarkerJs();
marker.setDraggable(true);

marker.addListener('dragend', function (event) {
var latLng = event.latLng;
var ds = app.datasources.Nomination;
ds.item.latitude = latLng.lat();
ds.item.longtitude = latLng.lng();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API lets you add [event listener to the marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker) and it seems that the most suitable for your case is `dragend` one:

```javascript
// Map's onAttach event handler
var marker = widget.getAddressMarkerJs();
marker.setDraggable(true);

marker.addListener('dragend', function (event) {
  var latLng = event.latLng;
  console.log(latLng.lat(), latLng.lng());
});
```

Comment: Hi Pavel , Thank you so much for your help. please correct me if im wrong. your script will just log the coordinates to a logfile right? what if i need to reflect the new marker coordinates back to a data table? will i just need to apply the "record" syntax i used from my example? sorry for the newbie question. thank you in advance!

Comment: I was not sure, if your code was correct that's why I used more abstract usage of the new coordinates to lower probability of spreading error-prone code. Definitely you can use the coordinates in a way you need.